# how to extract the string value in Android services from an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service

how to extract the string value in Android services from an activity?

My activity has a edit text, the entered string must be received in my services.

TempLaunch.java :

public class TempLaunch extends Activity {

```
  private EditText text;
  private Button okbtn;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.templaunch);

    addListenerOnButton();

  }

  public void addListenerOnButton() {

    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_newid);    
    okbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_newid);


    okbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          Toast.makeText(TempLaunch.this, "In Temp launch class ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          Toast.makeText(TempLaunch.this, text.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);



            Toast.makeText(TempLaunch.this, "I am in Main activity class ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });


    Intent i = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);

    i.putExtra("DD_URL", text.getText().toString());

    //startActivity(i);



  }
}
```

MusicService.java
public class MusicService extends Service {

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        String url = null;



            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String id = intent.getStringExtra("DD_URL");

            System.out.println("Rosh :" + id);
            Toast.makeText(MusicService.this, "I am in Service:"+ id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

...

Please help me out with this regard.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is i.putExtra() not working?

Comment: from the activity side, I am able to fetch the entered text.

Comment: But from services, I am not able to fetch the string using the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [sendBroadcast(intent);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29) which will broadcast the EditText from your Activity A.

Then you need to call [onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29) within your Service class. This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving an Intent broadcast, in your case will be sent from Activity A.

```
   private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
   {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            // Do something
        }
   };

    //Register your receiver in onResume:

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();        
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("SOME_ACTION");
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

   //Unregister the receiver in onPause:

    @Override
    protected void onPause() 
    {
        super.onPause();       
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
```